# How to ST_UNION by id?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

So I have second level administration data of a country with shapes in a PostGIS database. Now I actually need the first level administration level representation of the country, but here I only have the name of that first level admin and the names of its subdivisions as a text file (which do not need to match completely with the names I have in the DB).

Now I would like to manually remove the admin2 data entries and replace them with the admin 1 data. However, for the geometry column I was thinking to do a `ST_UNION` by ids of the admin 2 areas of one admin1 area. Is this possible? Right now there is no indicator of shared admin 1 information in the DB. Something like:

```
ST_UNION((SELECT geom FROM states WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)))
```

Comment: Cant you `groupby` some lvl? 1,2,3,4 havent got some common attribute?

Comment: There is none. I could add a column and write an admin 1 identifier for each admin 2 area. Just would like to know if there is a way without manipulating the table.

Comment: Why do not you want to `GROUP BY *the name of that first level admin*`?

Comment: Move the admin 1 information into the DB (into another table if you want), so that you can at least check whether the data is consistent. There is no problem joining the tables later.

Comment: @CL. Yes, I guess this is the best. But as I said, there is no common attribute to identify which admin 2 belongs to which admin 1. So right now my startegy is to add a column which I set `NULL` for each row that is not part of that country and then add an identifier of the admin1 into the other rows of that country. Then I `INSERT` a row with the data of the admin 1 area and its `UNION`ed geometry and delete the old admin2 areas.